# What set is this sealed bag of pink, purple, and white bricks from?

Tags: set-identification

I would like help identifying this bag of pink and purple LEGO bricks. It has three sets of eyes.

[image: bag of pink and purple bricks]

Answer (score 9):

Based on the [White Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Bar Frame Octagonal, Reinforced, Completely Round Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=75937&idColor=1#T=C&C=1) and the [Dark Pink Brick, Modified 1 x 2 x 1 1/3 with Curved Top](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6091&colorID=47&in=A)

This bag is part of [10696-1: Medium Creative Brick Box](https://brickset.com/sets/10696-1/Medium-Creative-Brick-Box)
[image]